# Writing to a file in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure

I am using this function to write to a file in Clojure.

```
(defn writelines [file-path lines]
  (with-open [wtr (clojure.java.io/writer file-path)]
    (doseq [line lines] (.write wtr line))))
```

But this always generates this error:

```
IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: write for 
class java.io.BufferedWriter in
clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:79)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you, for added clarity, add an example function call in your question? It is likely to confirm opqdonut's answer.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but might be interesting in this context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756909/in-clojure-1-3-how-to-read-and-write-a-file/7757674#7757674

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all, your function works just fine for many inputs:

```
Clojure 1.3.0
user=> (defn writelines [file-path lines]
  (with-open [wtr (clojure.java.io/writer file-path)]
    (doseq [line lines] (.write wtr line))))
#'user/writelines
user=> (writelines "foobar" ["a" "b"])
nil
user=> (writelines "quux" [1 2])
nil
```

However, when you try to pass in something weird we get the error you describe:

```
user=> (writelines "quux" [#{1}])
IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: write for class  java.io.BufferedWriter  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:79)
```

This error is because `BufferedWriter` has multiple overloaded versions of `write` and clojure doesn't know which one to call. In this case the conflicting ones are `write(char[])` and `write(String)`. With inputs like strings (`"a"`) and integers (`1`) clojure knew to call the `String` version of the method, but with something else (e.g. a clojure set, `#{1}`) clojure couldn't decide.

How about either ensuring that the inputs to `writelines` are indeed `String`s or stringifying them using the `str` function?

Also, have a look at the [`spit` function](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/spit).

Comment: Note: If you want to stringify an arbitrarily nested Clojure value, it's better to use `pr-str` rather than `str`. If the resulting string is fed directly to a stream, you should use `pr` (or `prn`) instead of the two-step `pr-str` followed by `print` or `.write`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
(defn writelines [file-path lines]
  (with-open [wtr (clojure.java.io/writer file-path)]
    (binding [*out* wtr]
      (doseq [line lines] (print wtr line)))))
```

If you look at the documentation for [BufferedWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) you'll see no corresponding method to the way you were calling `write` (whoops, I missed the inherited methods, silly me!). Binding to `*out*` is just easier all around, I think (unless you also want to be outputting debugging information, in which case it might be a bit trickier).

Answer (score 0):

Going by the exception message, lines is not a seq of strings, ints (chars) or int arrays.