# Why is line-seq returning clojure.lang.Cons instead of clojure.lang.LazySeq?

Tags: file-io, clojure, lazy-sequences, cons

According to the ClojureDocs entry for line-seq (http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/line-seq) and the accepted answer for the Stack question ([In Clojure 1.3, How to read and write a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756909/in-clojure-1-3-how-to-read-and-write-a-file)), line-seq should return a lazy seq when passed a java.io.BufferedReader.

However when I test this in the REPL, the type is listed as clojure.lang.Cons. See the code below:

```
=> (ns stack-question
     (:require [clojure.java.io :as io]))
nil
=> (type (line-seq (io/reader "test-file.txt")))
clojure.lang.Cons
=> (type (lazy-seq (line-seq (io/reader "test-file.txt"))))
clojure.lang.LazySeq
```

Wrapping up the line-seq call in a lazy-seq call gives a lazy seq, but according to the docs, this shouldn't be necessary: line-seq should return a lazy seq anyway.

Note:
Inside the REPL (I'm using nrepl) it seems that lazy seqs get fully realized, so I thought perhaps it was just a quirk of the REPL; however the same problem exists when I test it with Speclj. Plus, I don't think realizing a lazy seq has to do with what is going on anyway.

EDIT:
So I went to check the source code after mobyte's answer said there is a lazy seq in the tail of the cons...

```
1   (defn line-seq
2     "Returns the lines of text from rdr as a lazy sequence of strings.
3     rdr must implement java.io.BufferedReader."
4     {:added "1.0"}
5     [^java.io.BufferedReader rdr]
6     (when-let [line (.readLine rdr)]
7       (cons line (lazy-seq (line-seq rdr)))))
```

That call to cons would explain why the type of the return value of line-seq is clojure.lang.Cons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need "wrap" output `Cons` because it already has lazy seq as "tail":

```
(type (line-seq (io/reader "test-file.txt")))
=> clojure.lang.Cons

(type (rest (line-seq (io/reader "test-file.txt"))))
=> clojure.lang.LazySeq

(type (cons 'a (rest (line-seq (io/reader "test-file.txt")))))
=> clojure.lang.Cons
```

**Edit.**

> Note: Inside the REPL (I'm using nrepl) it seems that lazy seqs get
>   fully realized

Not correct. You can test it:

```
(with-open [r (io/reader "test-file.txt")] (line-seq r))
=> IOException Stream closed  java.io.BufferedReader.ensureOpen (BufferedReader.java:97)
```

It's because `line-seq` returns `lazy-seq` which is not fully realized and `reader` is already closed when repl tries to realize result later to print it. But if you realize it explicitly it would give normal result without any exceptions:

```
(with-open [r (io/reader "/home/mobyte/2")] (doall (line-seq r)))
=> ...  output ...
```

Comment: So I suppose that typing (line-seq my-buffered-reader) in the REPL and having it print out completely means the lazy seq is evaluated only for the print step, but not actually until then?