# lazy-seq -- cons outside or in

Tags: clojure

Should cons be inside (lazy-seq ...)

```
(def lseq-in (lazy-seq (cons 1 (more-one))))
```

or out?

```
(def lseq-out (cons 1 (lazy-seq (more-one))))
```

I noticed

```
(realized? lseq-in)
        ;;; ⇒ false

(realized? lseq-out)
        ;;; ⇒ <err>
        ;;;   ClassCastException clojure.lang.Cons cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IPending  clojure.core/realized? (core.clj:6773)
```

All the examples on the [clojuredocs.org](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/lazy-seq) use "out".

What are the tradeoffs involved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You definitely want `(lazy-seq (cons ...))` as your default, deviating only if you have a clear reason for it. `clojuredocs.org` is fine, but the examples are all community-provided and I would not call them "the docs". Of course, a consequence of how it's built is that the examples tend to get written by people who *just* learned how to use the construct in question and want to help out, so many of them are poor. I would refer instead to the code in clojure.core, or other known-good code.

Why should this be the default? Consider these two implementations of `map`:

```
(defn map1 [f coll]
  (when-let [s (seq coll)]
    (cons (f (first s))
          (lazy-seq (map1 f (rest coll))))))

(defn map2 [f coll]
  (lazy-seq
    (when-let [s (seq coll)]
      (cons (f (first s))
            (map2 f (rest coll))))))
```

If you call `(map1 prn xs)`, then an element of xs will be realized and printed immediately, even if you never intentionally realize an element of the resulting mapped sequence. `map2`, on the other hand, immediately returns a lazy sequence, delaying all its work until an element is requested.

Comment: line-seq has `cons` on the outside and has already caused some confusion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182702/why-is-line-seq-returning-clojure-lang-cons-instead-of-clojure-lang-lazyseq?rq=1

Comment: In fact, isn't it a bug for `line-seq` to consume the first line when no one has asked for it?

Comment: I do think `line-seq` is "wrong", but it's less crucial that `line-seq` be fully lazy, since it doesn't call an arbitrary function like `map` does. My guess was that `line-seq` is so old that its code was written back when lazy sequences worked differently than they do now. You can see some interesting history of line-seq at http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-222.

Answer (score 7):

With `cons` inside `lazy-seq`, the evaluation of the expression for the first element of your seq gets deferred; with `cons` on the outside, it's done right away and only the construction of the "rest" part of the seq is deferred. (So `(rest lseq-out)` will be a lazy seq.)

Thus, if computing the first element is expensive and it might not be needed at all, putting `cons` inside `lazy-seq` makes more sense. If the initial element is supplied to the lazy seq producer as an argument, it may make more sense to use `cons` on the outside (this is the case with `clojure.core/iterate`). Otherwise it doesn't make that much of a difference. (The overhead of creating a lazy seq object at the start is negligible.)

Clojure itself uses both approaches (although in the majority of cases `lazy-seq` wraps the whole seq-producing expression, which may not necessarily start with `cons`).

Comment: Good point about when the initial element is supplied as an argument; That's the first time I've heard of that.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not sure about the initial element supplied argument.  Wouldn't the calculated value be presented at almost the same speed whether inside `lazy-seq` or not?  In fact, the documentation for `iterate` says it will return a lazy-seq, but an exception is thrown when I call `realized?` on it.  Isn't that actually a bug?

Comment: You want `iterate` not to compute `(f x)` unless it is necessary. Therefore the consing of `x` to the front needs to be separated from the call to `f` by a `lazy-seq` layer. Thus, you could either define it as `(cons x (lazy-seq ...))` or `(lazy-seq (cons x (lazy-seq ...)))`; but then in the second case you end up with double the number of `lazy-seq` layers. As for `realized?`, that's a good point -- perhaps the docstring could use improvement. (Or you could argue that `realized?` should simply return `true` for non-lazy seqs, although my first instinct is that that's not the right way... Hm.)

Comment: I still don't understand the second case.  It may be a fundamental gap in my knowledge, but I'm playing around with `(defn iterate2 [f x] (lazy-seq (cons x (do (println "... iterate called") (iterate2 f (f x))))))`, and (f x) is not being called when I call `first` on the lazy seq.

Comment: I have just now pasted your definition into a 1.5.1 REPL and entered `(first (iterate2 inc 0))`. In result, I got an "... iterate called" printout and a return value of 0, as expected. In contrast, `(first (iterate #(do (println "...") (inc %)) 0))` returns 0 without printing anything.