# Returning all rows of a csv file except for the first row in Clojure

Tags: string, function, csv, clojure, return

This is what I have so far:

```
(defn cities []
    (with-open [rdr (reader)]
        (doseq [line (next (line-seq rdr))]
            (print line))))
```

I am able to print all the rows minus the first but am unable to return all the rows? How would I be able to do this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read a file in clojure and ignore the first line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013616/read-a-file-in-clojure-and-ignore-the-first-line)

Answer (score 2):

Do you see that `(next (line-seq rdr))` part?  That's returning the list without the first item.  Instead of printing it, you can just return it.

Here, however, you have to make sure that it is fully realized before the reader is closed.  You can do that with `doall`:

```
(defn cities []
  (with-open [rdr (reader)]
    (doall (next (line-seq rdr)))))
```