# Split lines in clojure while reading from file

Tags: file-io, clojure, split

I am learning clojure at school and I have an exam coming up. I was just working on a few things to make sure I get the hang of it.

I am trying to read from a file line by line and as I do, I want to split the line whenever there is a ";".

Here is my code so far

```
(defn readFile []
  (map (fn [line] (clojure.string/split line #";"))
  (with-open [rdr (reader "C:/Users/Rohil/Documents/work.txt.txt")]
    (doseq [line (line-seq rdr)]
      (clojure.string/split line #";")
        (println line)))))
```

When I do this, I still get the output:

```
"I;Am;A;String;"
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: You print the line, but not the split result.  Use `(doto (split...) println)` for debugging.

Comment: Man, that was so dumb. Thanks a lot!

Comment: to add to what cfrick said, this is because your split results are getting thrown away since line is immutable. You need to pass the results to println. See my answer for more details

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure if you need this at school, but since Gary already gave an excellent answer, consider this as a bonus.

You can do elegant transformations on lines of text with transducers. The ingredient you need is something that allows you to treat the lines as a reducible collection and which closes the reader when you're done reducing:

```
(defn lines-reducible [^BufferedReader rdr]
  (reify clojure.lang.IReduceInit
    (reduce [this f init]
      (try
        (loop [state init]
          (if (reduced? state)
            @state
            (if-let [line (.readLine rdr)]
              (recur (f state line))
              state)))
        (finally
          (.close rdr))))))
```

Now you're able to do the following, given input `work.txt`:

```
I;am;a;string
Next;line;please
```

**Count the length of each 'split'**

```
(require '[clojure.string :as str])
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io])

(into []
      (comp
       (mapcat #(str/split % #";"))
       (map count))
      (lines-reducible (io/reader "/tmp/work.txt")))
;;=> [1 2 1 6 4 4 6]
```

**Sum the length of all 'splits'**

```
(transduce
 (comp
  (mapcat #(str/split % #";"))
  (map count))
 +
 (lines-reducible (io/reader "/tmp/work.txt")))
;;=> 24
```

**Sum the length of all words until we find a word that is longer than 5**

```
(transduce
 (comp
  (mapcat #(str/split % #";"))
  (map count))
 (fn
   ([] 0)
   ([sum] sum)
   ([sum l]
    (if (> l 5)
      (reduced sum)
      (+ sum l))))
 (lines-reducible (io/reader "/tmp/work.txt")))
```

or with `take-while`:

```
(transduce
 (comp
  (mapcat #(str/split % #";"))
  (map count)
  (take-while #(> 5 %)))
 +
 (lines-reducible (io/reader "/tmp/work.txt")))
```

Read https://tech.grammarly.com/blog/building-etl-pipelines-with-clojure for more details.

Comment: What's the difference when I just use `line-seq` instead of `lines-reducible`?
Perhaps early termination?

Comment: Good question. When using `line-seq` you will create intermediate aggregates and have more garbage collection as a result. Also you will have to take care of closing the reader yourself (often accomplished with `with-open`).

Comment: Why is that? I thought that `transduce` would ensure that no intermediate collections are created.
By using `line-seq` instead of `lines-reducible` I meant using (almost) the exact same expressions you wrote: `(transduce (comp ... (line-seq ...`

Comment: Now I get what you mean.

(transduce
 (comp
  ...)
 +
 (line-seq (io/reader "/tmp/work.txt")))

also works, but two things to consider: 1) you have to close the reader yourself 2) line-seq will still create an intermediate lazy sequence. With lines-reducible you won't create this sequence.

Answer (score 8):

TL;DR embrace the REPL and embrace immutability

Your question was "what am I missing?" and to that I'd say you're missing one of the best features of Clojure, the REPL.

**Edit**: *you might also be missing that Clojure uses immutable data structures so*

consider this code snippet:

```
(doseq [x [1 2 3]]
   (inc x)
   (prn x))
```

This code does not print "2 3 4"

it prints "1 2 3" because x isn't a mutable variable.

During the first iteration  `(inc x)` gets called, returns 2, and that gets thrown away because it wasn't passed to anything, then `(prn x)` prints the value of x which is still 1.

Now consider this code snippet:

```
(doseq [x [1 2 3]] (prn (inc x)))
```

During the first iteration the inc passes its return value to prn so you get 2

**Long example:**

I don't want to rob you of the opportunity to solve the problem yourself so I'll use a different problem as an example.

Given the file `"birds.txt"` 
with the data `"1chicken\n 2duck\n 3Larry"`
you want to write a function that takes a file and returns a sequence of bird names

Lets break this problem down into smaller chunks:

first lets read the file and split it up into lines

`(slurp "birds.txt")` will give us the whole file a string

`clojure.string/split-lines` will give us a collection with each line as an element in the collection

`(clojure.string/split-lines (slurp "birds.txt"))` gets us `["1chicken" "2duck" "3Larry"]`

At this point we could map some function over that collection to strip out the number like `(map #(clojure.string/replace % #"\d" "") birds-collection)`

or we could just move that step up the pipeline when the whole file is one string.

Now that we have all of our pieces we can put them together in a functional pipeline where the result of one piece feeds into the next

In Clojure there is a nice macro to make this more readable, the `->` macro

It takes the result of one computation and injects it as the first argument to the next

so our pipeline looks like this:

```
(-> "C:/birds.txt"
     slurp
     (clojure.string/replace #"\d" "") 
     clojure.string/split-lines)
```

last note on style, for Clojure functions you want to stick to [kebab case](http://wiki.c2.com/?KebabCase) so `readFile` should be `read-file`

Answer (score -1):

I would keep it simple, and code it like this:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.test)
  (:require [tupelo.core :as t]
            [clojure.string :as str] ))
(def text
 "I;am;a;line;
  This;is;another;one
  Followed;by;this;")

(def tmp-file-name "/tmp/lines.txt")

(dotest
  (spit tmp-file-name text) ; write it to a tmp file
  (let [lines       (str/split-lines (slurp tmp-file-name))
        result      (for [line lines]
                      (for [word (str/split line #";")]
                        (str/trim word)))
        result-flat (flatten result)]
(is= result
  [["I" "am" "a" "line"]
   ["This" "is" "another" "one"]
   ["Followed" "by" "this"]])
```

Notice that `result` is a doubly-nested (2D) matrix of words. The simplest way to undo this is the `flatten` function to produce `result-flat`:

```
(is= result-flat
  ["I" "am" "a" "line" "This" "is" "another" "one" "Followed" "by" "this"])))
```

You could also use `apply concat` as in:

```
(is= (apply concat result) result-flat)
```

If you want to avoid building up a 2D matrix in the first place, you can use a `generator function` (a la Python) via `lazy-gen` and `yield` [from the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#generator-functions-for-lazy-sequences-a-la-python):

```
(dotest
  (spit tmp-file-name text) ; write it to a tmp file
  (let [lines  (str/split-lines (slurp tmp-file-name))
        result (t/lazy-gen
                 (doseq [line lines]
                   (let [words (str/split line #";")]
                     (doseq [word words]
                       (t/yield (str/trim word))))))]

(is= result
  ["I" "am" "a" "line" "This" "is" "another" "one" "Followed" "by" "this"])))
```

In this case, `lazy-gen` creates the generator function.
Notice that `for` has been replaced with `doseq`, and the `yield` function places each word into the output lazy sequence.

Comment: Generators might be convenient for some things, but I think in this case I'd just stick with `mapcat` to avoid the nested sequences.